# Stripe + PHP don't create charge

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to do the integration with stripe.
All happens well when I create the token

```
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    debugger;
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});
```

But when I redirect to my charge.php nothing happens

[image: REsult from the call of file charge.php]

If you see the print screen above it only shows the information I passed from the index page, but the print after creating a charge in stripe doesn't show. And when I enter in strip dashboard don't have any payment.
My code in charge.php

```
<?php
  require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
  
  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('my_secret_key');
  
  //Sanitize POST Array
  $POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  print_r($POST);

  // This is a $20.00 charge in US Dollar.
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(
    array(
        'amount' => 2000,
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'source' => $token
    )
  );

  print_r("Print here");
```

Comment: You never set `$token`. `$token = $_POST['stripeToken']`

Comment: Putting aside the specific problem, you should never use Stripe this way, it's a deprecated approach that hasn't been recommended since 2019. The recommended integration is Checkout/PaymentIntents since they support multiple payment methods/Apple/Google Pay and 3D Secure authentication https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

Comment: right, I'll try to follow this tutorial.
Thanks